# SQL wildcard matching column name in QuestDB

Tags: sql, questdb

I'm trying to do a wildcard match on a column name, but it looks like there is no support for `LIKE` and there is no reference to wildcard matching in the documentation. How can I get the following to work if I have some boards with device names with "ESP":

```sql
SELECT * FROM dev_data
WHERE device_name LIKE '%ESP%';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you should use regex matching

https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/where/#regular-expression-match

```
SELECT * FROM dev_data
WHERE  ~=(device_name,'.*ESP.*');
```